# ¿como puedo llenar un vector solo con numeros pares automaticamente?

Tags: java

Hice la clase operaciones, con 3 vectores que el vector A y B se deben llenar con la variable privada numeros de la Clase Vector, el problema es que al ejecutar en la main el codigo el vector A se imprime solo con numeros 0, el vector A se debe llenar automaticamente con el metodo,

```
public class Operaciones {
int vectora[]=new int[10];
int vectorb[]=new int[10];
int sumados[]=new int[10];


public void LlenarA(){
    int i=0;
    Vector v1=new Vector();
    for (int par = 2;i < 10; par+=2) {
        v1.setNumeros(par);
        vectora[i]=v1.getNumeros();
        i++;
}
    
}
public void MostrarA(){
           for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        System.out.println(vectora[i]);
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Falta mucha información en esta pregunta, en concreto el código de la clase Vector. Por favor edíta la pregunta para añadirla (usa el botón "Editar")

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema es acerca de cómo estás llenando los números, para empezar parece ser que haces operaciones innecesarias. Realmente no expresas qué hace tu clase `Vector`, pues al inicio pensé que era la clase propia de Java ([Vector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html)). Pero me imagino su comportamiento similar a la clase Vector de Java...

Te recomiendo evitar nombres de este estilo, pues no es una buena práctica.

Para tu problema, si sólo quieres llenar tu arreglo con datos pares secuenciales puedes simplemente llenar tu arreglo con el número `par` que indicas:

Clase Operations.java

```java
public class Operations {
    int[] vector_a=new int[10];

    public void fillVectorA(){
        int i=0;
        for (int par = 2; i < vector_a.length; par+=2)
            vector_a[i++]=par;

    }
    public void showVectorA() {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vector_a));;
    }
}
```

Clase main.java

```java
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Operations operations = new Operations();
        operations.fillVectorA();
        operations.showVectorA();
    }
}
```

Output

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Y si quisieras llenarlo con números aleatorios podrías usar el método [`Math.random()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random())

```java
public void fillVectorA(){
    int max = 100_000 / 2, min = -100_000 / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_a.length; ++i)
        vector_a[i]= (int) ((Math.random() * (max - min)  + min)) * 2;
}
```

```
[-5092, -88456, 41308, -37392, -65720, 95880, -42660, -67056, 28568, -34598]
```